# It seems I have 2 versions os python 3 installed. Ideally I Would want to use 3.6.4 for pygame but I have Tcl/Tk error(how do i fix this?)

Tags: python, pygame, macos-sierra

I want to use 3.6.4 for writing my code but it has Tcl/Tk may be unstable. Note the 3.6.3 I call from my terminal and the 3.6.4 id downloaded from python.org.

Ideally, I would want rid of 3.6.3 and have 3.6.4 but without the "Tcl/Tk may be unstable error"

I'm using Mac Osx Sierra.

Here is what I am referring to:
[image]

Comment: by "Ideally, I would want rid of 3.6.3 and have 3.6.4" are you talking about delete python 3.6.3 and keeping 3.6.4 or deleting pygame from python 3.6.3 and keeping it on 3.6.4?

Comment: Deleting 3.6.3 and keeping 3.6.4 with pygame, but fixing the Warning Tcl/Tk error that i have on 3.6.4.

Comment: you need to use conda to install pygame in your anaconda environment. `conda install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest setting up [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage your python versions and virtual environments.

Comment: Thank you looks great i will look into this.

Comment: Yes, conda is an option as well. I personally just find pyenv to be easier to install and more lightweight (if all you really care about is python versions and virtual environments).